# Reference Markov martingale Harmonic function

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales, harmonic-functions

I've just finished a course of stochastic process (discret martingale and markov chain).

I would like to go further, I heard it exists a link between martingale markov process and harmonic functions.

Do you have any reference to go deeper in this way ?

Thank you !

EDIT : Maybe you can give me some name of theory in which this kind of problem is studied, it would help me to find some books :). Thank you again.

Comment: Are you interested in the time-discrete or in the time-continuous setting?

Comment: I know only time discrete but if the book teach me what I need for time continuous it's okay :).

Comment: Also curious about this!